# How to populate combo box with values in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I have a database with 3 tables.

**Manufact:**
ID, Name, Decription

**Model:**
ID, Manufact_ID, Name

**Order:**
ID, Manufact_ID, Model_ID, Quantity, Date,

In Access I would like to have the normal table/datasheet view for Order which gives the following output

```
ID Manufact.Name Model_ID(combo box) Quantity Date  
1  LG            W3000H-BN            10       02-01-2009
2  SAMSUNG       SyncMaster 205BW      5       02-20-2009
3  SAMSUNG       SyncMaster 206BW      2       03-18-2009
4  Iiyama        ProLite E1902S-B1     1       05-13-2009
```

My problem is the combo box. I want to have only the list of the Models of the curent Manufacturer selectable in the combo box. e.g: only the SAMSUNG models if SAMSUNG is selected.
I tried to set the Lookup row source for Model_ID column as

```
SELECT Model.ID,Model.Manufact_ID,Model.Name,Order.Manufact_ID \ 
FROM Model, Order WHERE Order.Manufact_ID = Model.Manufact_ID
```

This is actually an Model INNER JOIN Order ON ... giving the wrong result.
How can I refer to the actual value of Order.Manufact_ID in the actual row's Lookup SELECT command? It's a variable value I cannot stringify.

Thanks!

strauss

Comment: If you insist on a datasheet, you have to use a form. You can't do what you want in a plain table datasheet. Indeed, you shouldn't have a combo box embedded in a table. And on a form with multiple records, it gets complicated if you have LimitToList set to TRUE, because the filter of the combo box list for the current record will cause other records to show blank values.

Comment: BTW, this problem is why I don't make continuous forms and datasheets with combo boxes editable -- it makes it too hard to validate data with filtered dropdown lists.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. A combo box on a form can only have 1 source, it cannot have different sources for each record on a datasheet or multi-record form.

Comment: Er, what? This seems like a simple cascading combo box question to me.

Comment: That is, a combo box can have only one rowsource at a time, but it can be altered at runtime or filtered based on a value in the current record.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read this post, which seems to be the same as yours. It provides a solution:

[Is there a simple way of populating dropdown in this Access Database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588)