# Creating a form in Access with two cascading look ups

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

All,

I want to create an Access 2007 form for capturing employee skills and projects.

The first selection a user would make is to select a Manager from a drop down.

that should generate a list of employees under that manager.

then select an employee and that would allow for adding multiple skills, years of experience, key resource flag, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588

Answer (score 0):

In the after_update event of the Manager dropdown, place code that selects the employees into whatever you want to display - listbox or a subform or another combo-box.

```
Private Sub Cb_Manager_AfterUpdate()
    Me.List59.RowSource = "select EmpID & '-' & EmpName from employee where manager = '" & Me.cb_Manager & "' "
    Me.List59.Requery
End Sub
```

Now in the onClick event of the Employee list, place code to do something with the Emp ID :

```
Private Sub List59_Click()
Dim emp() As String
emp = Split(List59.Value, "-")

MsgBox "Selected: " & emp(0)  ' ---- Or Open a form with the Emp ID as the filter??

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems a little complicated.

Comment: @Remou, what would you suggest then?

Comment: @Paul See the link in the comments to the question.