# Display data in combobox based on another combobox

Tags: database, vba, combobox, textbox, ms-access-2007

I have two tables:

```
'Project'
Fields: ProjectID, ProjectName

'Plans'
Fields: PlanID, PlanName, PlanDate, ProjectID
```

In Access 2007, on a form, I have three textboxes that display information from the three fields in the 'Plans' table. I have a combobox to select a specific *PlanName* which changes the textbox values to match my selection.

I want another combobox that displays all of the *ProjectNames* and then have the combobox that displays the *PlanName*'s change and only display those Plans where the ProjectID's match.

I followed [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4289) guide but it didn't work.

Would anyone give me a breakdown of what I need to achieve this?

Comment: Didn't work is not much of an error report. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is capture either the on_change or after_update event of your "Project" combobox. Then you want to reset the SQL of the "Plans" combobox (In your case the comboboxes are likely to be set via SQL statements although this isn't always apparent in design view). Something like this:

```
Private Sub cboProject_Change()

    cboPlans.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM tblPlans WHERE ProjectID = " & cboProject.Value
    cboPlans.Requery

End Sub
```

Best of luck

Comment: There is no need to constantly set the rowsource.

Comment: thank you, I did this and made some other small changes and I got it to work!