# how to populate textbox with the database value based on combobox change in access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am new to Access and vb and i have failed to get the result what i am thinking to get ,hope i will resolve with your help guys

->my access database contains one table with following fields
                    **firstname** lastname **middlename** phone

I have two combo boxes and two textboxes

1. combobox- it populates firstname and based on this selection the other combo box has to fill with last name which i did successfully with the help of Me.Combo2.Requery

but i dont know how to fill middle and phone in textboxes

here i am failing in mapping recordset and connectionstring with my table and getting result to textbox value can any one help on this

Comment: Are you working in MS Access? Are you using Jet/ACE or some other back end? If you are working in MS Access with Jet/ACE, why are you using a connection string and why have you not simply bound your table or query to the form?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I am using ms access with vb , how to bound query result to the text box value?

Comment: What do you mean by vb? VB.Net, VBA? Are you working within Access itself? If so, it is VBA.

Comment: yes i am working with access only

Comment: How to autofill textbox based on the combobox box selection from table result ?

Answer (score 0):

You still have not said where the connection string comes from or why. The big advantage of Access is that it is fast and easy, for the most part, you do not need connection strings.

First, select your table, then choose create form. This will create a *single* form bound to the table. You could have created a query first and chosen that instead.

That is it. You have a form that displays your data. The key to this is the property sheet for the form, which you can find by switching to design view and double-clicking the small square at the top left of the form just under the form name. The property sheet will show the name of the table or query on the Data tab under the Record Source propery. You can, of course, set this property manually.

[image: Form property sheet]

You can now add a combobox to select records, but you do not have to, there are navigation buttons at the bottom of the form.

To add a combobox that selects records on your form, you must have first bound a recordset to your form using the steps above. Next, ensure that the wizard is selected for the toolbox. Unless you have unselected it, it will be selected. Now choose combobox from the toolbox, it will open the wizard.

[image: Combobox wizard]

Choose find a record on my form and press next to choose the relevant ID field / column and any other fields that you need. When the wizard completes, in MS Access 2010 (and probably in 2007) it will add an embedded macro that finds your record and in earlier versions it will add code. Other properties set by the wizard will look something like this:

```
Row Source : SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname FROM Table1
Column Count : 3
Column Widths : 0cm;2.54cm;2.54cm
```

Your table should have an ID, add one before you start, if it does not. The wizard will not add a Control Source when this option is selected because it is not needed, in fact, it would be a disaster to add a Control Source to a combo that finds records. Once again, you can do this manually. The code to find a record might look something like:

```
Private Sub MyCombo_AfterUpdate()
    With Me.Recordset
        .FindFirst "ID=" & Me.MyCombo
    End With
End Sub
```

This works because the bound column of the combo is set to 1, the first field of the select statement, which is ID.

The combo includes two other fields / columns and you can refer to these in a textbox by setting the control source of the textbox to:

```
= MyCombo.Column(2) ''Lastname
```

Where you count columns from zero:

```
Row Source : ID (0), Firstname (1), Lastname (2)
```

Cascading combos are another story altogether, and you can read it here [How to synchronize two combo boxes on a form in Access 2002 or in Access 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289670) and here [Is there a simple way of populating dropdown in this Access Database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588)