# MS Access forms using a variable to run a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Can you pass a variable to a query which will populate a combo box? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the row source of a combobox in a number of ways. For example, you could include the following in the current event:

```
 Me.ComboX.RowSource = _
    "SELECT ID, Description FROM Table WHERE AText='" & MyVar & "'"
```

Alternatively, you can refer to a form in code or in design view:

```
 SELECT ID, Description FROM Table WHERE AText=Forms!AnOpenForm!AControl
```

You may also wish to consider cascading comboboxes : [Is there a simple way of populating dropdown in this Access Database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588)