# Refer to Current Record in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Consider those two tables in Access 2010:

## ActionReg

```
ActionID     Taskt1     Actiont1  
    1          t1         t1a1  
    2          t2         t2a1   
    3          t3         t3a1
    4          t1         t1a2 
    5          t1         t1a3
    6          t2         t2a2
```

## TaskReg

```
ActionID     Taskt2     Actiont2  
    1          t1         
    2          t2         
    3          t3
```

I give the field Actiont2 the following properties (in Lookup tab in Design  View):

- Display Control = ListBox
- Row Source Type = Table/Query

Now I want this query to retrive from Actiont1 into Actiont2 the records related only to  the value of Task2 so the result will be:

## TaskReg

```
ActionID     Taskt2     Actiont2  
    1          t1       (t1a1,t1a2,t1a3)  
    2          t2       (t2a1,t2a2)  
    3          t3       (t3a1)
```

I used:

```
SELECT ActionReg.Action1  
FROM ActionReg, TaskReg 
WHERE [ActionReg]![Task1]=[TaskReg]![Task2];
```

But it retrives all records in Action1 if Task1 = any record in Task2.

Comment: Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using INNER JOIN in your Query.

Comment: I used: SELECT ActionReg.Action FROM ActionReg INNER JOIN TaskReg ON [ActionReg]![Task]=[TaskRegr]![Task];and get the message "JOIN expression not supported"

Comment: @أحمد محروس You cannot join on form controls. I do not believe this is a good answer.