# Filtering using a combo box value in Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have 2 combo box's that are populated from a table and allows the user to select a product from that table to convert into smaller pieces of stock. What I need to do is filter the products in combo box 2 based on a section of the Product Code selected in combo box 1. Is this possible and has anyone any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to base the binding of combo box 2 on the selected value of combo box 1. Update the binding of combo box 2 so it references combo box 1, then re-query.

This link http://www.baldyweb.com/CascadingCombo.htm has a couple of methods in that should get you started.