# How do I remove list items from a dropdown based on another dropdowns selection in the current form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 drop downs in my 'Add a Physician' form. One is for selecting the University and the other is for selecting the department. I would like to have the department (there are 6 list items) list items change depending on which University (there are 2 list items) is selected. I would also like to have the selection reset the department drop down if the user selects the other University.

If the University of Alberta is selected I want to remove "Neurology" and "Physical Medicine & Rehabilitation" from the department drop down.

This is the coding I have so far:

```
Private Sub cboUniversity_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo err_trap

If Me.cboUniversity = "University of Alberta" Then
    Me.cboDepartment.RemoveItem "Neurology"
    Me.cboDepartment.RemoveItem "Physical Medicine & Rehabilitation"
End If

err_trap_exit:
    Exit Sub

err_trap:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description     & " - University - After Update"
    Resume err_trap_exit

End Sub
```

I have tried it on the cboUniversity Change, AfterUpdate, and LostFocus events as well as on the cboDepartment Change event and while I don't get any error messages it doesn't actually remove the two list items "Neurology" and "Physical Medicine & Rehabilitation" from the department drop down list. What am I doing wrong or missing?

I also have no idea how to get it to reset if the selection in the University drop down is changed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple way of populating dropdown in this Access Database schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema)

Comment: Hi I had a look at that thread and I'm hoping to do this in VBA not in a macro and I'm having a difficult time translating the thread to my situation in VBA.

Comment: The post asked for a macro, but the very useful answer is VBA.  If you are not able to apply it, I should ask you:  Does the question in that post seem to relate?

Comment: This might be much more clear:  http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0028.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your cboUniversity_AfterUpdate procedure, rather than removing items from cboDepartment, change the rowsource of cboDepartment accordingly - eg

```
Private Sub cboUniversity_AfterUpdate()
    if cboUniversity = "University of Alberta" then
        cboDepartment.RowSource = ... 'New ValueList, or New SQL which omits the unwanted departments
    else
        cboDepartment.RowSource = ...
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: If I do this will it eliminate the data I already have? I have an extensive database with many entries that have their university and department already selected, so the drop down list is populated.

Comment: Typically the combo box will be an unbound control, even when the form may be based on a recordset.  VBA code is what makes use of the entry, not an underlying recordset.  Therefore the data is not affected.

Comment: Ok so I used this code and it didn't work; here is the code verbatim:
    
    Private Sub cboUniversity_AfterUpdate()
    
        If cboUniversity = "University of Alberta" Then
            cboDepartment.RowSourceType = "Value List"
            cboDepartment.RowSource = "[Family Medicine];[Medicine];    [Neurosurgery];[Pediatrics]"
            Me.cboDepartment.Requery
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to populate the #2 combo box.

1. You can base it on a value list, and make a revision to the list.
2. More usefully perhaps in this case, you can base the #2 combo box on
   a query and filter its results( or otherwise revise the query).

Either solution makes more sense than `RemoveItem` (which I'm not sure exists, really... sounds like something from `DOM` manipulation).

Instructions may help: [access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0028.htm](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0028.htm)

Comment: So I run into problems because the drop down isn't populated using a table, I simply entered in the items for the drop down list. Sorry to ask so many questions I'm just confused as to how the code on the link will eliminate the 2 values for me.