# ACCESS 2010 - Autopopulating text fields based off of two comboboxes

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, combobox

I have two tables right now. One is called Workstations[ID, WorkstationName, Image, Operating System] and the other is Machines[ID,Asset Tag, Serial Number, MAC, Comments]. I have two comboboxes right now. One is for the workstation table that shows a list of all the workstationname's(cboWorkstationName) and the other is for the Machines table that shows a list of all the AssetTags (cboAssetTags)

The goal in making this form is that when I select a value in cboWorkstationName, I would like it to autopopulate all the text fields based off of the Workstations Table, the combobox cboAssetTags autopopulate the fields related to the Machines table based off of the second combobox. In the end, I want to be able to save different Asset Tag data to any workstation easily by just using the drop down lists.

Right now, cboWorkstationName autopopulates the text fields based off of the Workstations Table and cboAssetTags, but does not populate the textfields that are based off of the Machines table. However, when I click an asset tag (from the second combobox) it autopopulates the related fields. It's just not filling every field.

In regards to how I'm autopopulating, for the first combobox, I bound the form to the first table, and set Inherit Value List to yes. For the second combobox, I just set the Control Source to the ID. For the text fields below the second combobox, I wrote the following code for the OnChange event.

```
Me.txtSerialNumber.Value = Me.cboAssetTag.Column(2)
Me.txtMAC.Value = Me.cboAssetTag.Column(3)
Me.txtComments2.Value = Me.cboAssetTag.Column(4)
```

I'm thinking I have to add a line of code somewhere so that it refreshes/runs the second combobox when I change the first one.

If you need any clarifications please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
Private Sub cboWorkstationID_Change()
Dim db As Database
Dim rec1 As Recordset
Dim rec2 As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Workstations WHERE ID = " &     Me.cboWorkstationID.Column(0) & "")
Set rec2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Machines WHERE ID = " & Me.cboAssetTag.Column(0) & "")

Me.txtComments.Value = rec1("Comments")
Me.txtImage.Value = rec1("Image")
Me.txtOperatingSystem.Value = rec1("Operating System")
Me.txtLocation.Value = rec1("Location")
Me.txtSerialNumber.Value = rec2("Serial Number")
Me.txtMAC.Value = rec2("MAC")
Me.txtComments2.Value = rec2("Comments")


Set rec1 = Nothing
Set rec2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have Me.cboAssetTag.Requery anywhere?

Comment: yes, I tried adding it for the OnChange event for the cboAssetTag combobox but it didn't work. I'm thinking may i need to add it to the cboWorkstationName? 

Edit: Just tried it, didn't work either. I'm thinking that I have to maybe write something that makes the second box update as if was an actual action done to that combobox.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you used a query to fill the textboxes.  What I would do is write a function, and execute that function in the OnChange event of both combo's.  Something like:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec1 as Recordset
Dim rec2 as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
set rec1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Workstations WHERE ID = " & Me.cboWorkstationName.Column(0) & "")
set rec2 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Machines WHERE ID = " & Me.cboAssetTags.Column(0) & "")

Me.txtWorkstationName.Value = rec1("WorkstationName")
Me.txtSerialNumber.Value = rec2("Serial Number")
Me.txtMAC.Value = rec2("MAC")
etc...

Set rec1 = Nothing
Set rec2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

You can fill in the rest of the fields accordingly.  Just make sure your combo's have a default value, or you have some type of error trapping/coded default value so it will run properly the first time you change a combo.

Comment: I disagree, I think fetching the data to a combobox and using columns, as impilied in the OP, is the way to go.

Comment: Just curious why you think pulling all that data into a dropdown is better than minimalizing what comes through the pipe?

Comment: for the Me.txtWorkstationName.Value = rec1("WorkstationName") part, is it just for all the different text fields I have that I want autopopulated?

Comment: Yes.  You will be updating every text field every time you change the values in one of your dropdowns.  You can split that up if you like, or force the user to make a choice from both dropdowns and instead put a "Submit" button on your form and run the function when the Submit button is clicked.

Comment: do I need to include the comboboxes too? Right now I'm getting an error saying Method or data member not found. But that's probably an issue with my field names.

Comment: The combo boxes need to be on your form.  This code will be reading the values from your combo box (assuming the IDs are in column(0) and the text is in column(1)) and then pulling the record from each table that matches the IDs (column(0)) from your combos.

Comment: A combobox will have one recordset, you have three - the combo and two others.

Comment: i'm going to post the code I have so far. it's still throwing that error. I've included all the textfields in the code, and checked all the field names to make sure they all match up. I'm still not sure whats going wrong. Could you just quickly check if there are any syntax errors?

Comment: Remou - Yes, but there's actually 2 combo boxes and they're essentially being populated with the entire respective tables.  That's a lot of unnecessary data coming through the pipe.  santaaimonce - I would put a break in the code and step through it.  See exactly which line is throwing the error.  It's much easier to debug if you can narrow it down.

Comment: Would the two comboboxes have the exact same code? Right now, it populates the first time I click an option from the first combobox but it populates the wrong info in the second and their related textfields. Any other changes to the first combobox only changes its related text fields, not the 2nd cbo and its text fields.

Comment: Yes, you would need the identical code in both combos.  Or, ideally, you would rename that Sub to something like, "Private Sub UpdateComboInfo" or whatever, and then in the OnChange event of both combos you would just put "Call UpdateComboInfo".  This way, if you ever need to edit it, you only need to edit it in one place.  I always try to reduce confusion by doing this, it's just less of a hassle in the long run.

Comment: hmm, sadly, it's still not working. Thing is that, when I change the cboWorkstationID, it doesnt change cboAssetTag. Do i need to add a line of code in the middle where it says Me.cboAssetTag = rec2("Asset Tag")? or something that forces the Asset Tag to change when I change the cboWorkstationID?

Comment: Hit the Googles for "Cascading Combo Boxes VBA".  It's a fairly common request.