# Access 2010 VBA how to check value of a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Alright, just a warning, I'm a complete rookie with VBA and Access, but I'm plugging away at it.

I've got a form with some listboxes on it, what I want to do is hide or show certain listboxes and fields of the form based on the "parent" listbox's selection.

I.e. "location" listbox contains many choices, one of them called "Canada"

When the user selects "Canada" I want the form to show another box called "provinces"

Current code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
MsgBox "Form Loaded"
    If Forms![Tickets]![location] = "Canada" Then
    MsgBox "location is Canada!"
End If
End Sub
```

The msgBox is in the if statement simply for me to see if the if statement is being triggered, whenever I figured this out I'll change that to the code I want executed.

I thought I knew how to reference the controls on the forms from VBA but I might be doing that wrong. I come from a PHP/Mysql background so I'm still grasping the language.

Cheers

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588

Comment: Okay, I had a look but it's a little murky to me. I've got the listboxes and such, the event is what I'm struggling with. I've been able to trigger the event just fine, as long as it is outside of my If statement, the if statement itself isn't being met for the message box to pop up.

I think I'm trying to select the control incorrectly?

Comment: Tried the following code:
    Private Sub location_Click()
MsgBox "Description was clicked!"
    If Trim(Me.location) = "Detachment Page" Then
        MsgBox "Description was clicked!"
    End If
End Sub

Similar to your event: 

    Private Sub cboNode_GotFocus()
    If Trim(Me.cboLocation & "") = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please select location"
        Me.cboLOcation.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

it didn't trigger the if statement or the box. I'm missing something obvious I'm sure of it.

Comment: What is the SQL of your listbox? Perhaps it is not equal to 'canada', it may be equal, for example, to 2. You can click on an item and using ctrl+G to get the immediate window, type ?Screen.ActiveControl

Comment: Also, make sure that the event line on your properties page is set to `[Event Procedure]`

Comment: Okay, I've done both of those suggestions, it turns out that the ?Screen.ActiveControl command when run and my desired selection is selected it gives me a "1", so I changed my if statement from "Canada" to "1" and it still won't trigger the message box. Is it maybe an issue with this line?

If Forms![Tickets]![location] = 1 Then ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49478/discussion-between-remou-and-david-morin)

Comment: Issue solved by Remou in chat! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SQL of a listbox is set to:

```
SELECT Id, SomeOtherField FROM aTable
```

Then the value of the list box is Id, not SomeOtherField.

In this case you should say:

```
If Me.[location] = 1 Then  ''Where 1 is the Id you want.
```

To check the value of a control, you can click on an item and use ctrl+G to get the immediate window, then type

```
?Screen.ActiveControl
```