# Refreshing a query when updating a form

Tags: ms-access, combobox

How does one update query results that are used to populate a combo box in MS-Access?  Forgive the question if it is too simple but I'm just starting with Access.

My situation works like this:
1. On my form there is a combobox(call it #1) to choose clients names from
2. There is a second combo box that lists individual items that are associated with the clients(in my case it is farm fields)
3.  This second combo box is populated from a query that is run based on the selection the first combo box
4. My issue is that the second combobox only updates if I open the query and run it.  I want the query to run automatically when I open make a selection in Combobox number one.

I'm assuming that what I want to do is possible through the Event properties.  I have struggled to determine the correct method and syntax to make what I want work.  Or is there a better method to acheive my desired result?  Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Cascading Combo Box.  Essentially, you want to run a query in the OnChange event of the first combo box that will update the results of your second combo box.  It's a lot to cover, so I'd suggest looking at [this page](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Cascading_Combo_Boxes) and coming back if you have something specific to ask once you've tried some code.

Comment: Please do not suggest on change for comboboxes, the event will run when a letter is typed.

Comment: You're right, it should probably be on the AfterUpdate event instead.