# filter table via cascaded combo boxes

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

First, let me just say I am not familiar with Access, so dumb questions, poor organization, etc. will abound. The boss kind of threw me at this project, so here I am.

I have 4 cascading combo boxes, named BilletMaterial, BilletNumber, TestType, and Axis, that filter each other based on what's selected. My next step is to use those to filter a table, which for now is just a listbox called OutTable. It has an indefinite number of fields. As far as code for trying to update the table goes, this is all I have at the moment.

```
If IsNull(Me.Axis) Then
    Me.FilterOn = False
Else
    Me.Filter = "OutTable = """ & Me.Axis & """"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

That's in the AfterUpdate event of the Axis combobox. It doesn't apppear to do anything, and I have no idea what to change or add. Any help would be great.

Comment: What does this mean? --> *"filter a table, which for now is just a listbox"*

Comment: @HansUp I wasn't sure if a listbox is the way to go with this. It's subject to change, according to advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your AfterUpdate statement, you need to change the record source of your OutTable control.

```
Me.OutTable.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Axis = '" & Me.Axis.Value & "'"
```

Comment: No, you do not, you can refer to the form and requery. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 for example. It saves problems with data types.