# MS Access - populate combobox value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a cascade of 2 comboboxes in a subform: cmbEquipmentType and cmbModel

cmbEquipmentType datasource is select statement " SELECT Type from EquipmentType"

And the type is like this:

Spoons (value 1)

Forks (value 2)

Knives (value 3)

And the user can select Forks and have it populate when the user goes back into the form again (after saving data).

cmbModel is a cascade, when the user selects the equipment type, the select statement is generated and the list populated.  This works fine.  (Here is the code btw)

```
   If cmbEquipmentType.Value = 1 Then
        cmbIdentifier.RowSource = "SELECT Chambers.Identifier FROM Chambers;"
                cmbIdentifier.ColumnCount = 1
        cmbIdentifier.BoundColumn = 1
        cmbIdentifier.ColumnWidths = "3"

    End If
```

And it saves to the database fine.

THE PROBLEM:

When I go back to the form, the cmbModel.value is not populated.

But I can get the value from here:

Dim id As String
id = Me![ReportData subform]![Identifier]

How do I get it to use the bound value?  The control Source is set to Identifier

All other textboxes/listboxes work, just this one is broken.

Thanks

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927256/is-there-a-simple-way-of-populating-dropdown-in-this-access-database-schema/927588#927588 may help.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by calling the OnEnter from the main form.load procedure.

Private Sub Form_Load()

    [Form_ReportData subform].cmbIdentifier_Enter

End Sub