# ComboBox Access Match on ID but Display Category

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I am working on a project but have run into a wall with Access's combo-boxes.  I've attached an image so things (hopefully) make more sense when I describe my situation.
I have two combo-boxes on a form, the left one is called cmb_body_system, and the right one is called cmb_icd9code.

What I am trying to do is have the left box display three options, the three from the body_system_type table: infectious, circulatory, respiratory. From there, the second box will display the matching description in the ICDLight table column titled icd9Description.

I have gotten as far as getting the left box to display the bodyID's associated with each matching Icd9Description, but I can't get further than that. The VBA that I have on these is:

`Private Sub cmb_body_system_AfterUpdate()
    cmb_icd9code.RowSource = "SELECT ICD9Description FROM ICDLight WHERE ICDLight.bodyID = " & Me.cmb_body_system & ";"
End Sub`

And as you can see, it's working, but I want to go that one step further and don't know what/how to search for this exactly. I mean, I don't even know how inaccurate/accurate the title is for that matter.

[image]

Comment: The search is cascading combos, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/927588/2548

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not well versed enough to properly understand Fionnuala's answer from the link, and be able to use it to find my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rephrase your question. From your question title, I think this is what you need.

1. Select your cmb_body_system
2. Go to property sheet
3. Under Format tab:

   4. Column Count = 2
   5. Column Widths = 0cm;  <- there is a semicolon
4. Under the Data Tab

   7. Bound Column = 1
   8. Row Source Type = Table/Query
   9. Row Source = "SELECT * FROM BODY_SYSTEM_TYPES"

Now your combobox will show "bodysystem" as display text and Bodyid as value